# Discrete Math on Induction and proof: $\sum_{i=1}^n i\cdot i! = (n+1)!-1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show by induction that the following formulas hold. N

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i\cdot i! = (n+1)!-1$$

Not sure how to go about this problem. Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: or Σⁿ_i=1 i( i!) = (n+1)! -1

Comment: Can you please edit in your attempt? Initial statement, basis step, inductive hypothesis for p(k), then proof of p(k+1) with subbed in inductive hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the equality is true then $n=1$: $1\cdot 1! =1 =2! -1$. Then, the basis of induction is true.

Now, suppose that the equality is true for $n=k$, i.e.,
$$\sum_{i=1}^k i\cdot i!= (k+1)! -1. $$

Then, for $n=k+1$ we obtain
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i\cdot i!=\sum_{i=1}^k i\cdot i! +(k+1)(k+1)!=(k+1)!-1 +(k+1)(k+1)!=$$
$$=(k+1)!\cdot[(k+1)+1]-1=(k+2)!-1. $$

Then, the results follow by induction.